# webpack-bundle-analyzer is not working as expected

Tags: angular6, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I updated an angular project from version 5 to 6, now I am trying to analyze bundle size using webpack-bundle-analyzer, but the output is not as expected. I tried the same before updating the version it worked as expected [after version update in angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEHsX.png)

[same project before update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8MuZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the webpack-bundle-analyzer package and try again....